# How to grep multiline comments in website source code?

Tags: curl, awk, sed, grep

I'm a penetration tester writing a tool for basic web application enumeration (gathers all links, email addresses, form field parameters, and comments) on the target URL.

Using `curl` I'm able to get single line comments from the source code of the target URL.

The following shows all single line comments:

```
curl <url> -s -L | grep '<!--.*-->' | sed -e 's/^[[:space:]]*//'
```

I'm having trouble trying to grep multiline comments.

How would I go about achieving this using `curl` + `grep`? or is `awk`/`sed` a better alternative?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can make use of sed's `/regexp/,/regexp/` range:

```
curl...|sed -n '/<!--/,/-->/p'
```

Answer (score 2):

Using regex to parse HTML or XML files is essentially not done. Tools such as `sed` and `awk` are extremely powerful for handling text files, but when it boils down to parsing complex-structured data — such as XML, HTML, JSON, ... —  they are nothing more than a sledgehammer. Yes, you can get the job done, but sometimes at a tremendous cost.  For handling such delicate files, you need a bit more finesse by using a more targetted set of tools.

In case of parsing XML or HTML, one can easily use [`xmlstarlet`](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/docs.php).

In case of an XHTML file, you can use :

```
$ curl ... | xmlstarlet sel --html -t -m '//comment()' -v . -n
```

However, As HTML pages are often not well-formed XML, it might be handy to clean it up a bit using [`tidy`](http://tidy.sourceforge.net/). In the example case above this gives then :

```
$ curl ... | tidy -q -numeric -asxhtml --show-warnings no     \
  | xmlstarlet sel --html -t -m '//comment()' -v . -n
```